# Unique elements inside lists of list

Tags: list, python-3.x, duplicates, unique

If I have a nested list like:

```
l = [['AB','BCD','TGH'], ['UTY','AB','WEQ'],['XZY','LIY']]
```

In this example, 'AB' is common to the first two nested lists. How can I remove 'AB' in both lists while keeping the other elements as is? In general how can I remove a element from every nested list that occurs in two or more nested lists so that each nested list is unique?

```
l = [['BCD','TGH'],['UTY','WEQ'],['XZY','LIY']]
```

Is it possible to do this with a for loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

counts = Counter(chain(*ls)) # find counts
result = [[e for e in l if counts[e] == 1] for l in ls] # take uniqs
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter([b for a in l for b in a])
for a in l:
    for b in a:
        if counts[b] > 1:
            a.remove(b)
```

Edit: If you want to avoid the (awfully useful standard library) `collections` module (cf. the comment), you could replace `counts` above by the following custom counter:

```
counts = {}
for a in l:
    for b in a:
        if b in counts:
            counts[b] += 1
        else:
            counts[b] = 1
```

Comment: Is there any way that does not involve imports?

Comment: I'm not sure why you ever would; `collections` is in the standard library, and you'll probably want it in your toolbox. In any case, I updated the answer with an alternative.

Comment: I am just a beginner, I have not learnt about any import modules

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat short solution without imports would be to create a `reduce`d version of the original list first, then iterate through the original list and remove elements with counts greater than 1:

```
lst = lst = [['AB','BCD','TGH'], ['UTY','AB','WEQ'],['XZY','LIY']]

reduced_lst = [y for x in lst for y in x]

output_lst = []

for chunk in lst:
    chunk_copy = chunk[:]
    for elm in chunk:
        if reduced_lst.count(elm)>1:
            chunk_copy.remove(elm)
    output_lst.append(chunk_copy)


print(output_lst)
```

Should print:

```
[['BCD', 'TGH'], ['UTY', 'WEQ'], ['XZY', 'LIY']]
```

I hope this proves useful.